# Tile styling in Open Street Map (with Leaflet)

Tags: openstreetmap

Is it possible to use different colors for Tiles in Open Street Map?

In Google Maps API you can style the map - is there a same feature in Open Street Map or even better are there any different tile templates on the web for download and use in OSM?

Comment: Have you heard of [stamen](http://maps.stamen.com/#watercolor/12/37.7706/-122.3782)?

Comment: Yes I did, but it's an extra service. Is'nt there something directly in OSM?

Answer (score 10):

OpenStreetMap project provides map data. In order to display web maps OSM data needs to be pre-processed and rendered. Depending on whether you use raster (for example default leafler) or vector tiles (mapbox-gl) steps to modify styles are completely different. Raster styles are usually generated using mapnik rendering library with mod_tile and apache web server. OSM data needs to be imported into PostgreSQL database. Depending on the amount of data you want to process it can take different time from couple of hours for single city to days for the whole planet and require very good hardware (6-8 cores/ 32 GB ram and higher). Then you need to edit special CartoCSS styles to change map appearance. Vector maps and tiles is completely different story but it will require comparable efforts to create your custom map style.
What I suggest is to go and find OSM maps provider that have different styles from default OSM by the way here is an excerpt their tile usage policy (https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/):

```
OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not.
```

So look at these providers, they can save you a lot of time and money:

- https://openmaptiles.org
- https://getmaps.io
- https://stadimaps.com
- and others from https://switch2osm.org/providers/

Comment: Check out this one also: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview